# 2D kernel density plot with 3d version in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, kernel-density, r-plotly

My dataset looks like this:[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbV7g.png)
I adopted code here:
[2d kernel density plot](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/#2d-kernel-density-estimation)

```
kd <- with(test, MASS::kde2d(x=`Avg Protein`,y=`Avg Oil Content`,n=100))
p <- plot_ly(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z) %>% add_surface()
p
```

while, my result is not correct.The peak is not at the correct location.[plot with peak at the wrong location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vtXC.png)

This my another version of histogram contour vision which I used same dataset.The result is more convincing.[plot with peak at the right location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BWs2.png)

```
p <- plot_ly(test, x = ~`Avg Protein`, y = ~`Avg Oil Content`) %>%
  add_histogram2dcontour()
```

I wonder how can I correct my kernel density code with 3D version which has consistent result with the histogram contour vision. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how debugging can occur by simply looking at the code and output. Would need to see the data as well.

Comment: I just uploaded the dataset pic

Comment: Please copy/paste the data in the question instead. Images of datasets are useless.

Comment: You need to make `z` a matrix object rather than a data.frame column.